# Disable 'Reassign Task' and 'Request Change' Options in 2010 Workflow

Tags: workflow

In the OOTB 2007 Approval Workflow, users had the choice whether to allow reassignment of a workflow task and/or whether to allow the approver to request for a change. These options were presented as two checkboxes in the 2007 template. How is the option to disallow these behaviors acheived in the OOTB 2010 version of the Approval Workflow?

Edited: I should have clarified that few end users have access to SharePoint Designer in our environment, so I was looking for a method to allow users to specify this from the UI.

Answer (score 3):

- In SPD, select the Approval workflow (your copy, rather than the original as advised by Kishork)
- Click *Edit workflow* under Customization
- Click on *Approval* in the action: Start Approval process on Current Item
- Uncheck *Reassignment* and *Change Requests* under Settings
- Publish

Answer (score 0):

- Open site in SPD
- Select Workflows in the Site Objects on left nav
- Right click on approval workflow and make a copy (Don't make changes to the original WF)
- Click on the Approval Task Workflow
- Uncheck Reassignment
- Save and associate with your list/doc lib